# Identify which of the following are Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Pick out the cases which imply that the sequence is Cauchy.
>   A. $|x_n -x_{n+1}| \leq 1/n$, $\forall n$
>   B. $|x_n -x_{n+1}| \leq 1/n^2$, $\forall n$
>   C. $|x_n -x_{n+1}| \leq 1/2^n$, $\forall n$

For all the cases the $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n-x_{n+1})=0$. So, does all imply that the sequence is Cauchy?

Comment: A sequence of real numbers is Cauchy if and only if it converges. Can you decide which of your sequences converge?

Comment: B and C are correct but I m not sure about A.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can be a bit more explanatory.@Sobi

Comment: Being Cauchy means that the difference between consecutive terms gets smaller and smaller the greater $n$ becomes. Does this hold for all the cases?

Comment: yes it is @FrancescoCarzaniga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It is $|x_n-x_m|\leq |x_n-x_{n+1}|+\dots+|x_{m-1}-x_m|$.

Especially for (a): try $x_n=1+\dots+\frac{1}{n-1}$, for $n=2,3,\dots$

Comment: Yes you are right this satisfies the condition but it is not Cauchy.

Comment: How can we prove (b) and (c) are correct?

Comment: The series $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^2}, \sum_{n}\frac{1}{2^n}$ are convergent, hence their partial sums sequences are Cauchy. Use the hint above for the details. e.g. for (b): Let $\varepsilon>0$ find $n_0$ s.t. for all $n,m\geq n_0$ it is $\sum_{k=n}^{m}\frac{1}{k^2}<\varepsilon$. Then for all $n,m\geq n_0$ it is $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.